# Async test with nightwatch and mocha runner

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai, end-to-end, nightwatch.js

I am trying to define few tests using nightwatch.js and mocha runner. I want to test how my javascript library works across different browsers.

My code is fairly simple and looks like that

```
const expect = require('chai').expect;

describe('InfinitiSpec', function() {

  beforeEach((client, done) => {
    client.url(`file://${__dirname}/../../dist/index.html`);
    done();
  });

  after((client, done) => {
    client.end(() => done());
  });

  it('should be five', (client) => {
    client.execute(function() {
      // test javascript here
    }, [], () => {
      expect(2 + 2).to.equal(5)
    });
  });
});
```

The problem I have is that nightwatch does not pass `done` callback to the tests, therefore even trough if single test assertion fails test itself is still looks like it's successful.

```
vladmiller:infiniti-tracking-evolution vladmiller$ nightwatch 


  InfinitiSpec
 ✖ AssertionError: expected 4 to equal 5
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/vladmiller/Projects/xxx/xxx/test/browser/infiniti.spec.js:18:24)
    at HttpRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nightwatch/lib/index.js:322:20)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at HttpRequest.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at HttpRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nightwatch/lib/index.js:351:15)
    at emitThree (events.js:97:13)
    at HttpRequest.emit (events.js:175:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nightwatch/lib/http/request.js:155:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:166:7)
    ✓ should be five (3322ms)


  1 passing (3s)
```

How can I test async javascript using nightwatch + mocha + chai? Also maybe one can recommend better stack for testing JS in selenium? 
Thanks

Comment: I've never seen that `client` parameter before. mocha passes `done` as the first parameter in `it/beforeEach/afterEach/before/after`. You should import `client` like you import `chai.expect`.

Comment: @Louy I think you used standard mocha. See the doc reference http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#using-mocha Nightwatch can integrate in mocha behind the scenes(?)

Comment: @Louy I never used selenium before, and particularly liked nightwatch because it can load configs and gives me nice CLI tools. However I have to use mocha directly I'd rather then switch to webdriver

Comment: ah yeah. "Each testcase receives the `client` object, `hooks` also receiving a `done` callback for async operations."

Comment: so one thing to note here: `✓ should be five (3322ms)` i.e. it's waiting for the async operation to end but ignoring the error.
I think you can't use chai with nightwatch.

Comment: [nightwatch already offers an api similar to chai](http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#bdd-expect-assertions) anyway so I think your problem is here. get rid of chai and try again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nightwatch uses a patched version of mocha that doesn't support async tests. The solution is to use standard mocha instead, but the related documentation (http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#using-the-standard-mocha) is incomplete, and you'll have troubles getting access to page objects in that context.

After spending one hour trying to setup Nightwatch with standard mocha, I decided to go back to plain Selenium Webdriver. And honestly, I don't regret it.

If you want advice on how to do Nightwatch-like Page objects with just Selenium, check out http://marmelab.com/blog/2016/04/19/e2e-testing-with-node-and-es6.html